# Function that makes an array out of words entered as an argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, null

```
    function makeArray(text){
            var array = [];
            var word = null;

            for(var i = 0; i<text.length; i++){
            if (word == null) {
                word = "";

                    if(text[i] != "," && text[i] != " " && text[i] != "." && text[i] != "   "){
                        word += text[i];
                    }
                    else{
                        array.push(word);
                        word = null;
                    }
                }
                return array;
            }
var array = makeArray("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nunc varius urna sed pede. Suspendisse sit amet lacus. Vivamus consectetuer fringilla ligula. Nunc metus lorem, pretium adipiscing, sollicitudin nec, ultrices quis, nulla. Phasellus nec nulla a eros adipiscing ultrices. Nulla fermentum lectus. Pellentesque ac risus eu massa auctor bibendum. Cras vulputate, nisi eget gravida condimentum, nisl justo tincidunt magna, rutrum imperdiet dui justo vel risus. Donec sit amet pede. Etiam facilisis mauris vitae risus. Ut a neque. Suspendisse augue est, elementum nec, lobortis vel, pulvinar vitae, sapien. Curabitur venenatis enim sit amet sapien. Mauris fermentum interdum eros. Mauris feugiat adipiscing nisl. Donec non nunc. Donec ante enim, eg."

for(var i = 0; i<array.length;i++){
        document.write(i+ ". "+array[i]+"<br />");
    }
```

I am trying to build a program that can take a long piece of text and tell you if a word only occurs one time throughout the text. I have not yet written the rest of the code as you can see, but when i ran this to test if it would successfully return every item in the array, the web browser just displays a blank screen, compared to this code

```
function makeArray(text){
        var array = [];
        var word = "";

        for(var i = 0; i<text.length; i++){
            if(text[i] != "," && text[i] != " "&& text[i] != "." && text[i] != "    "){
                word += text[i];
            }
            else{
                array.push(word);
                word = "";
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
for(var i = 0; i<array.length;i++){
            document.write(i+ ". "+array[i]+"<br />");
        }
```

which works properly, but if a character sequence such as ". "(period + space) comes up it will add to the array an item with a value of `""`, due to the `word = "";`. I tried to eliminate this from happening by using the `null` type, because w3schools.com says that "Variables can be emptied by setting the value to null", but when I use the type `null` it causes an error, why is this?

Answer (score 0):

- Create an empty string called "word" ('')
- Add letters to it, one at a time ('L','Lo','Lor','Lore','Lorem')
- Word ended, so push to array ('Lorem')
- Reset word to null (null)
- Add letters to it, one at a time ('nulli','nullip','nullips','nullipsu','nullipsum')

What you are trying to do is reseting to empty string, you don't want null.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want to create an array of words from a string. A simple way to do it is to use [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method, and as an argument to `split`, pass a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). Something like this:

```
var array = text.split(/[\W]+/);
```

`split` above creates a new array by splitting `text` everywhere, where the included RegExp meets one or more sequential characters, which are not alphanumeric (or underscores), in `text`.

What comes to the blank screen, it appears because you're using [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) after the page has been parsed. Doing so will create a new document, and all the content of the current document will be lost. Rather create an element with an `id` to the page, and do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('id_of_an_element').innerHTML = array.join('<br />');
```

[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is a "contrary" method to `split`, and it creates a string from an array.

[A live demo at jsFddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ec3kc/).